# Dry-running psql scripts

Tags: postgresql

*Psql* script files may (and typically do) contain *psql*-specific instructions, includes and variable substitutions that are resolved client-side. I am looking for a generic way of getting the sequence of SQL commands as they would be sent to the PostgreSQL server by *psql*, after all client-side processing if done. Furthermore, this should be available offline. Therefore, solutions involving socket-sniffing live runs or using rolled-back transactions are excluded. Would someone know of a way that this can be achieved?

**Edit:** Because of *psql* conditional meta-commands (`\if`, ...) that can depend on the result of the evaluation of previous SQL statements, I understand that it is not possible to have complete resolution in all cases (which may be why *psql* doesn't provide a dry-run option). A valid solution to this question could still simply ignore *psql*'s conditionals, though.

Comment: Define "offline". Would a local DB with a copy of the remote DB structure count as "offline"? And if your requirements are "no, it must work with psql alone", you can always change the source code of psql and insert some additional logging...

Comment: Good question. I would define *offline* as without requiring database user authentication. *Psql* already allows logging of resolved commands (with the ```--echo-queries``` switch), but there seem to be no way of preventing communication with the server.

Comment: Actually, spoofing the server end of the connection just to accept user authentication could be a solution, but this needs to work without the actual database, which may either not exist, not be accessible, or be too big for replicating it locally.

Comment: Again, preventing actual communication is easy if you modify the psql source. You may also have success by locally installing one of the many postgresql proxies, if at least one of them can be configured to have in fact no connection to a real database. But I don't know, I haven't looked at any of the proxies in such detail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Modifying *psql*'s source code is not really an option given the context in which this solution will be implemented. But having a look at the proxies, that's a very good ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Bash script expands *psql*'s *\include* (*\i*) and *\include_relative* (*\ir*) meta-commands in-place and outputs a single resolved stream to *stdout*. As I'm posting it, I'm spotting a couple of areas that could be improved upon (mostly merging the two `read -r line` instructions), but the script does nonetheless work fine as-is (as far as I tested it):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

incl='*([[:space:]])\\@(include?(_relative)|i?(r))+([[:space:]])*'

# Recursively process single \include (\i) or \include_relative (\ir) meta-command
process() {
    # If current line is an '\include' ('\i') or '\include_relative' ('\ir') meta-command, substitute with file contents
    if [[ "$1" == $incl ]]; then
        # Read included file's name
        filename="$(echo "$1" | awk '{print $2}')"
        # Read included file's contents and process each line recursively
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            process "$line"
        done < "$filename"
    # Else, echo the line
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

# Output usage information with '--help' or '-h' switch
if [[ ' --help -h ' =~ " $1 " ]]; then
    echo "USAGE: pg_psqlexpand [workdir] [-h|--help]"
    echo
    echo "Expands in place `\include' (`\i') and `\include_relative' (`\ir') meta-commands in psql scripts."
    echo
    echo "Connect pipe or use redirection for I/O."
    echo "Paths are resolved relative to `workdir' (defaults to current working directory)."
    exit 0
else
    # If working directory is specified, cd into it (defaults to '.')
    cd "${1:-.}"
    while read -r line; do
        process "$line"
    done
fi
```

This allows for merging complex, multi-file scripts into a single file for inspection. It also allows one to pipe in-place such scripts to *psql* running as the *postgres* superuser from locations that *postgres* has no access to (typically locations in the caller's home directory):

```bash
## Merge into single file
$ pg_psqlexpand < entry_point.psql > merged.psql

## Pipe to psql running as postgres
$ pg_psqlexpand < entry_point.psql | sudo -iu postgres psql
```

I've been using the above script for almost a week so far and it has been working fine. The only drawback that I ran into is that debug information regarding file names and line numbers is lost in the process. As a work-around, I add these meta-commands at the top of my *psql* entry-point, giving me enough information for debugging without much difficulty:

```
-- Error handling
\set VERBOSITY verbose
\set SHOW_CONTEXT errors
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

It should be noted that this script is not syntax-aware and will therefore substitute any include-like sub-string that could appear inside strings or a double-quoted literal identifiers.