# Creating a secure transcient duplicate of a folder for consumption by ‘psql’ running as ‘postgres’

Tags: bash, postgresql

This is a question about finding an ideal way to deal with a particular situation.

In a folder under my home folder is a group of *psql* script files that reference each others through `\include_relative` meta-commands. These scripts sometimes need to be run through *psql* as a database superuser. Because *postgres* is peer-authenticated, I must call *psql* with `sudo --user postgres`. But since the files are in my home folder, the OS user *postgres* has no access to them. Now, if there was only a single script file to read, I could simply use a shell redirection, as in `sudo -u postgres psql < ~/psql/myscript.psql`, but as soon as `myscript.psql` includes another file, then *psql* won't find it.

There are various simple and trivial ways of making this work. However, I exclude manually copying/moving/deleting files around every time I need to run a script, and I want to retain the ability to freely move around and rename the source folder and script files without breaking things. Furthermore, this is a mission-critical production server, so interfering with the PostgreSQL service, as in changing the cluster's configuration — for example, creating additional superusers, or changing authentication settings — is out of the question. Ideally, we want this to be transparent to the rest of the server, which excludes solutions involving pre-configured (e.g. ftab, systemd-mount) bind-mount and overlays, or other changes to the server's configuration.

I am looking specifically for a command that makes the script folder available on-the-fly to *psql*, and only for the duration of the script run. My solution so far is this:

```bash
$ sudo mount --bind -o ro,X-mount.mkdir=777 ./psql ~postgres/tmp && \
  sudo -iu postgres psql -f ~postgres/tmp/myscript.psql; \
  sudo umount ~postgres/tmp && \
  sudo rmdir ~postgres/tmp
```

But still, I find it verbose and I'm trying to improve on it. And I don't like the creation of a `tmp` folder in `~postgres`. Has anybody better ideas?

**Edit:** Following @larsks' comment below, I realize that my above solution has a privacy flaw in systems where multiple user are given access to the *postgres* user.

Comment: Move those commands into a script so you just run `sudo myscript` instead. I'm not sure anything is going to be more graceful than that. Or set `a+x` on your home directory (and possibly intervening directories) so that the `postgres` user can read the files in their existing location; it doesn't appear to be a file ownership or permissions problem (you're never calling `chown` or `chmod`).

Comment: Yes, a script or an alias is a good way to conceal the verbosity. The permission thing, we've thought of it already, but the scripts should ideally stay private to each particular user (sudoer), and giving any access to *postgres* would allow anyone with sudo access to *postgres* to see each other's scripts. This could become an issue. This is actually already the case, I realize, for a short window while the mount is active. Thanks for initiating this line of thoughts.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the straight-forward solution of simply creating a `postgres` role for your own username, and then granting rights to that role to do whatever it is you need to do?  Doing it this way would be roughly analogous to using `sudo` to lock down a specific user's `root` privileges instead of giving them the root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a shell script `run-with-tempdir` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d ~postgres/tmp/psqlXXXXXX)
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" EXIT

tar -C "$tmpdir" -xf- &&
  psql -f "$tmpdir/$1"
```

And then we run it like this:

```
tar -C psql -cf- . | sudo -u postgres run-with-tempdir myscript.psql
```

This (a) doesn't expose your home directory to the postgres user, (b) doesn't expose your scripts to any other users on the system (because the tmpdir is create with mode `700`), (c) doesn't require bind mounts (which can cause problems if an error prevents the unmount from happening), and (d) cleans up after itself automatically.

Comment: Point (c) and (d) are two more good issues raised. Regarding this proposed solution, though, isn't anyone who can sudo as *postgres* still able to just do ```sudo -u postgres ls ~postgres/tmp/psqlXXXXXX``` and see all the scripts file there?

Comment: That depends on your `sudoers` configuration: do you allow arbitrary commands? Or do you just allow people to run the `run-with-tempdir` script?

Comment: I ended up using a different approach for ensuring script privacy. I realized that all requirements of the problem that I'm trying to solve cannot be met with a "temporary duplicates" approach, which **must** involve some extant of server configuration (as larsks pointed out above, limiting the privileges of sudoers with regard to what commands they can run as *postgres*). So I'll go ahead an accept larsks' answer because it does answer the initial question by bringing significant improvements over my initial attempt.

Comment: For reference, my solution to this other question ended up providing the answer to the issue underlying the present question (the "different approach" mentioned in the above comment): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712751/dry-running-psql-scripts